# SQL remove curly bracket

Tags: sql

When i select a column i get the below results

{"ac92b9f2-c7c7-4d2a-982b-c06bb218a5ed"}

Is there a way to remove the {""} from the results?

Comment: What is your query and what RDMS are you using?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Including the select , the SQL specific dialect/version/database you are using and the table definition DDL would increase your chance to get an answer . Be more specific please, I guess you are reading an identity column from MS-SQL server but could be many other things.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: this looks like a SQL server's GUID. If yes you can try `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), [your_GUID_column])`

Answer (score -1):

This should work on most rdbms (though you should specify your rdbms anyway):

```sql
select substr(your_column, 3, length(your_column) - 4)
from your_table
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  Select
     replace(replace(replace(col_name, '{', ''), '}', ''), 
         '"',") from table;
```

Or as per your data you can simply use

```
      Select
      Substr(col_name, 3,LENGTH(col_name)-4)
      from table;
```

Check this for reference demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e24574/3

Answer (score -1):

When you get the GUID value in your application from the database use this in your SQL query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(300), MYGUID)
```

instead of

```
SELECT MYGUID
```

Where MYGUID is the name of a field in your table.

This conversion CONVERT(VARCHAR(300), MYGUID) will remove bracket inside your application and you will get the value "ac92b9f2-c7c7-4d2a-982b-c06bb218a5ed" instead {"ac92b9f2-c7c7-4d2a-982b-c06bb218a5ed"}.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.